# How to add where in Yii model search method?

Tags: yii, cgridview

I have four tables in my DB as shown(user, user_test, test, status). There is a M:M to relation between user and test and therefore user_test is a Gerund between them.
The status table has statuses for both user_test and test tables. The tablename field in status table shows which table the status belongs to as shown in the lower image.

I want to show table user_test in a CGridView with the related data in all the three tables user, test and status. All is well as the relations are correct.

Problem: When I want to show status.name in my CGrid like:

```
array(
    'header'=>'Status',
    'value'=>'$data->status->name',
),
```

It gives me name 'completed' but it is the status of table 'test' and the correct one should be 'confirmed' as status_id in user_test is 2.

Any help?

[Database design](http://www.softhem.se/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/db.png)
[Status table](http://www.softhem.se/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/status.png)

```
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with=array('user','test','status');

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);
    $criteria->compare('test_id',$this->test_id);
    $criteria->compare('status.id',$this->status_id);
    $criteria->compare('bonus',$this->bonus);
    $criteria->compare('user.signum',$this->signum, FALSE);
    $criteria->compare('user.email',$this->email, FALSE);
    $criteria->compare('test.seats',$this->seats, FALSE);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'attributes'=>array(
                'signum'=>array(
                    'asc'=>'user.signum',
                    'desc'=>'user.signum DESC',
                ),
                'email'=>array(
                    'asc'=>'user.email',
                    'desc'=>'user.email DESC',
                ),
                'seats'=>array(
                    'asc'=>'test.seats',
                    'desc'=>'test.seats DESC'
                ),
                '*',
            ),
        ),
    ));
}
```

UPDATE:
Relations are here:

```
//UserTest
....
return array(
        'status' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Status', 'status_id'),
        'test' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Test', 'test_id'),
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        'testtimeslots'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TestTimeslots','timeslots_id'),
    );


 // Test
  return array(
        'testType' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TestType', 'test_type_id'),
        'status' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Status', 'status_id'),
        'testCriterias' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TestCriteria', 'test_id'),
        'testTimeslots' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TestTimeslots', 'test_id'),
        'userTests' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserTest', 'test_id'),
    );


    // User
    return array(
        'userLanguages' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserLanguage', 'user_id'),
        'userTests' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserTest', 'user_id'),
    );

    // Status
    return array(
        'tests' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Test', 'status_id'),
        'userTests' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserTest', 'status_id'),
    );
```

UPDATED: The sql I want to generate is:

```
        SELECT * FROM user_test AS UserTest
           INNER JOIN user ON user.id=UserTest.user_id
           INNER JOIN test on test.id=UserTest.test_id
           INNER JOIN (SELECT status.value, name from status where  status.tablename='user_test') AS Status ON (Status.value = UserTest.status_id)
```

Comment: You should also show us how the relations are defined.

Comment: I am making it clear once more that I am comparing userTest.status_id with status.value (NOT status.id).

Comment: Once solution I figured out so far is I used a function inside model Status:                                                              public function StatusName()
 {
  $id= $this->status_id;
  $model = Status::model()->find("tablename='user_test' AND value= $id");
     return $model->name;
 }          and then in my Cgridview I retrieved the value like: array(
      'header'=>'Status',
      'value'=>'$data->StatusName()',
     ),

Answer (score 0):

Add before the compare part

```
$criteria->addCondition('Where a = b');
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addCondition-detail

It takes an overload of and or or like so

```
 $criteria->addCondition('Where a = b', AND);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition="user_name='john' and user_status='active'";
```